# How do I import Ant Design React UI library and css?

Tags: css, reactjs

I am very new to UI libraries and CSS in React. I'm using a data picker from Ant Design: https://ant.design/docs/react/introduce.

They provide CodePen examples and in the CSS tab you can see this:

`@import 'antd/dist/antd.css';`

However, when I add this to my CSS stylesheet which I import in to the component using `import './Component.css';` I get the error

> Module not found: Can't resolve './antd/dist/antd.css'

in the components folder.

I have installed the npm package but can't get the CSS to work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you share your package.json?

Answer (score 4):

in 2023:
import "antd/dist/reset.css";

Comment: while updating the antd version to 5.X then the files under the below import are not available "~antd/lib/style/themes/dark. Less"; "~antd/dist/antd.dark.less" "~antd/lib/style/themes/default. Less"; where is the alternative for these less in the latest version? Please provide the support on these points as well

Answer (score 3):

Make sure `antd` is installed correctly and it's visible in your `package.json` it should be there

`"antd": "3.19.2"` assuming you ran `npm i antd`

as well as importing it in your component with

`import { DatePicker } from 'antd';`

Then import the style manually in your component

`import 'antd/dist/antd.css';`

Comment: @That'sEnam Can you explain more? What error are you seeing?

Comment: "import 'antd/dist/antd.css';" --

It does not seem to be a good idea to import an almost 700 KB file with 25 000+ lines into your component/page...