# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'antd/dist/antd.css'

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "cryptoapp",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@ant-design/icons": "^4.8.0",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "antd": "^5.1.0",
    "axios": "^1.2.1",
    "chart.js": "^4.1.1",
    "html-react-parser": "^3.0.4",
    "millify": "^5.0.1",
    "moments": "^0.0.2",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-chartjs-2": "^5.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.5",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
```

and I am trying to import in index.js

```
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
```

but this throws the above error .

I tried to import the above in App.css by
doing @import '~antd/dist/antd.css' as i created my app using npx create-react-app .
But this doesn't seem to be working .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I import Ant Design React UI library and css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56500258/how-do-i-import-ant-design-react-ui-library-and-css)

Answer (score 5):

you are importing wrong file. As per the [documentation](https://ant.design/docs/react/use-with-create-react-app) it should be

```
import 'antd/dist/reset.css';
```

Comment: while updating the antd version to 5.11.3 then the files under the below import are not available "~antd/lib/style/themes/dark. Less"; "~antd/dist/antd.dark.less" "~antd/lib/style/themes/default. Less"; where is the alternative for these less in the latest version? Please provide the support on these points as well

Comment: in my case I have added  to my global.css - @import 'antd/dist/reset.css';